# don't work pendrives 64 Gb 14.04

Tags: 15.04, usb-drive

I work with Ubuntu 15.04, and doesn't recognize the pendrives with 64 Gb.
Is it correct?

Comment: When you say "I work with Ubuntu 15.04" does that mean you currently have it installed on your computer? Or are you trying to install it? When you say "doesn't recognize the pendrives with 64Gb", where are you expecting to see the drive? Are you trying to put an Ubuntu image on the drive so you can install? Or are you trying to put ordinary files on the drive from an Ubuntu machine?

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu 15.04, and when I connect a pendrive with 64 Gb appears a message: "Unable to mount 64 Gb volume"

Comment: 15.04 is End of Life, and not supported here.

Comment: Does the USB drive work on other USB ports, computers, or operating systems? What about other USB drives on the same setup? The size of the drive shouldn't matter (unless you add a bunch of zeroes).

Comment: This USB drive works well in Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your 64 GB drive is formatted exFAT rather than FAT32. 64 GB and larger capacity oftentimes are. I believe live USB must use FAT32. You should be able to reformat the 64 GB drive to FAT32 using something like Gparted.